# How to make just one selected option color differently with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a dropdown list and in the dropdown I have an empty caption to show as a default placeholder ("ex. Crawler Excavator"). This should be in color lightgray. I underline this should be only in lightgray if selected and if empty caption labe, all other labels (options) when selected or in dropdown list should be black.

I am able to manage the lightgray color for the selected item, but now all the other non-empty items become also lightgray which should be black. See GIF for clarification and JSFiddle code;

https://jsfiddle.net/fhgdrxz9/

```css
element.style {}

select.form-control {
  text-overflow: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-border-radius>input,
.custom-border-radius>select,
.custom-border-radius div>span>span>.select2-selection .select2-selection--single {
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #DADADA;
}

.empty-label-gray>div>select,
.empty-label-gray>select {
  color: #9e9e9e !important;
}

select.form-control {
  padding-right: 30px;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='15px' height='8px'><polyline id='Line' fill='none' stroke='%23555555' points='0.5 0.5 6 6 11.545361 0.5'></polyline></svg>);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: calc(100% - 10px) center;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  transition: border 0.3s;
  color: #333333 !important;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: none;
}

.form-control {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 50px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  color: #555;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}

input,
button,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  margin: 0;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

user agent stylesheet select:not(:-internal-list-box) {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

user agent stylesheet select {
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: -internal-light-dark(black, white);
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: start;
  appearance: menulist;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: pre;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  background-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(59, 59, 59));
  cursor: default;
  margin: 0em;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(118, 118, 118), rgb(133, 133, 133));
  border-image: initial;
}

.listview-stylingless.mx-listview>ul>li {
  padding: 0;
  cursor: default;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

user agent stylesheet li {
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

.mx-listview>ul {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

user agent stylesheet ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #F8F9FB;
  font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}

:root {
  --partner-primary: #FFDD00;
  --partner-text: #000000;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ment.style {}

.empty-label-gray>div>select>option,
.empty-label-gray>select>option {
  color: black !important;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

user agent stylesheet option {
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
  white-space: pre;
  min-height: 1.2em;
  padding: 0px 2px 1px;
}

select.form-control {
  text-overflow: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.empty-label-gray>div>select,
.empty-label-gray>select {
  color: #9e9e9e !important;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  transition: border 0.3s;
  color: #333333 !important;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: none;
}

.form-control {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 50px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  color: #555;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}

input,
button,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  margin: 0;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
}

user agent stylesheet select {
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: -internal-light-dark(black, white);
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: start;
  white-space: pre;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  cursor: default;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}

.listview-stylingless.mx-listview>ul>li {
  padding: 0;
  cursor: default;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

user agent stylesheet li {
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

.mx-listview>ul {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

user agent stylesheet ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #F8F9FB;
  font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}

:root {
  --partner-primary: #FFDD00;
  --partner-text: #000000;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="mx-name-dropDown2 default-alert custom-border-radius empty-label-gray mx-dropdown form-group no-columns"><label class="control-label" for="32.MarketPlace.Service_PurchaseConfigurations.dropDown2.100_bom_555" id="32.MarketPlace.Service_PurchaseConfigurations.dropDown2.100_bom_555-label">Range *</label>
  <select id="32.MarketPlace.Service_PurchaseConfigurations.dropDown2.100_bom_555"
    class="form-control">
    <option value="">ex. Crawler Excavator</option>
    <option value="E10_ADT">Articulated Dump Truck</option>
    <option value="E20_BHL">Backhoe loader</option>
    <option value="E30_BUL">Bulldozer</option>
    <option value="E40_CHE">Crawler Excavator</option>
    <option value="E50_EC">Compressor</option>
    <option value="E60_EG">Generator</option>
    <option value="E70_M_C">Mobile crusher</option>
    <option value="E80_M_G">Motor Grader</option>
    <option value="E90_M_S">Motor Scraper</option>
    <option value="E100_MDCE">Midi Excavator - Crawler</option>
    <option value="E110_MDWE">Midi Excavator - Wheeled</option>
    <option value="E120_MHE_C">Mini Excavator</option>
    <option value="E130_OTH">Other</option>
    <option value="E140_RDT">Rigid Dump Truck</option>
    <option value="E150_SSL">Skid Steer Loader</option>
    <option value="E160_T_C">Trash Compactor</option>
    <option value="E170_T_H">Telescopic Handler</option>
    <option value="E180_W_D">Wheel Dozer</option>
    <option value="E190_W_E">Wheeled Excavator</option>
    <option value="E200_WL_L">Wheel Loader</option>
    <option value="E210_WL_S">Wheel Loader - Small</option>
    <option value="E220_EDT">Electric Dump Truck</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

So anyone tips how I can just color the selected empty caption and all other dropdown labels black? I also want to remove the empty caption from the dropdown list (ex. Crawler Excavator).

[image]

Comment: Please share here the code in a code snippet. not in a jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry wasnt aware of that, thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0):

Dont think it's possible with only CSS, but here is an Javascript example. https://jsfiddle.net/gjf4n9eh/

**Javascript**

```
const select = document.getElementById("32.MarketPlace.Service_PurchaseConfigurations.dropDown2.100_bom_555");
        
select.addEventListener("change", () => {
   if(select.value === ""){
     select.style.color = 'gray';
   } else {
     select.style.color = 'black';
   }
})
```

**CSS**

```
select {
  option {
    color: black;
  
    &:first-child {
      color: gray;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Eriks. thanks for your answer but the empty caption is gray in the dropdown list, that should be black or removed totally from JUST the dropdown list. What do you advice for that?

Comment: @user3394645 you can change the color for the first option in selectbox with CSS. with `first-child`. If you don't want it to be selectable but still show up on page load. use  `<option value="" disabled selected>ex. Crawler Excavator</option>`

Comment: @user3394645 updated with the new fiddle so the first option is not gray

Comment: Thanks, now the initial default selected one is black also, should be gray. I'll play around.

Comment: was not able to solve it...anyone an idea how i just can color the empty